# PHP Fatal Error when trying to add a user on a inventory system website with XAMPP

Tags: php

[The browser is showing this error whenever i try to add a user in my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHI3D.png)
Xampp Version:8.2.12
Heres my code in line 1-12:

```
<?php
  $page_title = 'Add User';
  // require_once('includes/load.php');
  // Checkin What level user has permission to view this page
   page_require_level(1);
  $groups = find_all('user_groups');
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['add_user'])){

   $req_fields = array('full-name','username','password','level' );
   validate_fields($req_fields);
```

Im expecting my system to add a user in it but the error always shows whenever i click the add user button

Comment: As the error says, undefined function page_require_level. Where do you have that defined?